# How to match numeric with grep

Tags: regex, cygwin, grep

I have a line in my log file that has the version number of the build in question.
it will always be 1.43.93.* e.g.

```
<some text > Version=1.43.98.7488, <more text>
```

I just want to extact the version number.

None of the following return anything:

```
grep -G -m 1 1.43.98\.\d+ mylog.txt
egrep -m 1 "1.43.98\.\d+" mylog.txt
```

The build number occurs in mutliple places in the logfile (which is why I'm passing the -m flag with a value of 1), but obviously I'm only interested in the first match.

Any tips will be appreciated. I'm using Cygwin (GNU grep 2.6.3).

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

First make sure that `\d` works - you will probably have to set the -P option (perl regex) and test it against a something simple.

I spent many hours wondering why my regex worked on one platform and not another only to find that grep on one machine had been built without the -P option enabled. All `\d` regexs were being ignored and I had to use either `[:digit:]` or `[0-9]` instead `:(`

Answer (score 2):

I don't have cygwin env. the following grep line was tested under linux.

```
kent$  cat a
<some text > Version=1.43.98.7488, <more text>
<some text > Version=1.43.98.7488, <more text>
<some text > Version=1.43.98.7488, <more text>
<some text > Version=1.43.98.7488, <more text>
<some text > Version=1.43.98.7488, <more text>

kent$  grep -oPm 1 '(?<=Version=)[0-9\.]+(?=,)' a
1.43.98.7488


kent$  grep -V
GNU grep 2.5.3
```

Comment: thanks. the -o flag was the key and in the end, egrep -om 1 1.43.98.[0-9]+ a did the trick

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -o -m 1 1.43.98.[[:digit:]]* a
```